# Prevent all the styles from Styles.css in angular 6 components

Tags: css, angular, styles, angular6, angular-components

I have a special scenario to solve. There is an existing angular 6 application where few of the html tags are overridden in Styles.css (Eg: Button, H1, p, etc - I do understand it's not recommended). I'm building another set of components (15+) in the same codebase where I want to prevent/override all the styles from Styles.css and want to apply styles from external stylesheet.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question. It's not always not recommended to override the default styles, creation of classes are always recommended. If you are working with classes. Just rewrite the custom style in component's style sheet, It will override the global styles

Comment: I agree with you. That's how the application is build by previous developers. I can not touch the existing code unfortunately. I'm building new application on the same codebase since few of the existing components I have to reuse here. I just want to prevent all the styles from Styles.css on my components (15+) specifically in a better way.